# CSS transiction and JS toggle at the same moment

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transactions

I've got not displayed block with JS toggle performance on mouseover/mouseout(http://jsfiddle.net/4bytz20h/2/):

html:

```
<div id="menu" onmouseover="toggle_extra_panel()" onmouseout="toggle_extra_panel()">
    <a>hover me</a>
    <div id="list">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function toggle_extra_panel() {
    var  sys_val = document.getElementById('list');
    sys_val.style.display = (sys_val.style.display == 'none' || 
                             sys_val.style.display == '') ? 'block' : 'none';

}
```

css:

```
#menu #list {
     display: none;
}
```

---

Trying to add some animation effects(by CSS transictions)(http://jsfiddle.net/4bytz20h/1/):

html(without changes):

```
<div id="menu" onmouseover="toggle_extra_panel()" onmouseout="toggle_extra_panel()">
    <a>hover me</a>
    <div id="list">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- empty here -->
```

CSS:

```
#menu #list {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}

#menu:hover #list {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 2.5s ease-in;
}
```

---

But I lost (forgot to use) my JS toggle code. In next example I'm trying to combine JS logic(display form 'none' to 'block' when mouseover) and CCS transiction effect(height and width from '0' to 'auto' when mouseover). Here not wroking well code(http://jsfiddle.net/4bytz20h/):

html(without changes):

```
<div id="menu" onmouseover="toggle_extra_panel()" onmouseout="toggle_extra_panel()">
    <a>hover me</a>
    <div id="list">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

js(without changes):

```
function toggle_extra_panel() {
    var  sys_val = document.getElementById('list');
    sys_val.style.display = (sys_val.style.display == 'none' || 
                             sys_val.style.display == '') ? 'block' : 'none';

}
```

css:

```
#menu #list {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: height 1.5s ease-out;
    transition: width 1.5s ease-out;
    background: #d5d5d5;
     display: none;
}

#menu:hover #list {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: height 2.5s ease-in;
    transition: width 2.5s ease-in;
}
```

Better way to execute all desires using only by ccs transictions.
But how about this combine way: in one moment JS makes the item to be displayed and in this same moment ccs tries to draw rectangle-text-area from 0 to bigger gabarite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're trying to do.

```css
.hide {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 2.5s ease-in;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  opacity: 0;
}
.current:hover .hide {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="current">HOVER ME
  <div class="hide">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4bytz20h/3/
Now, after some corrects, we got code, that contents in themself pretty effects and got JS reference, that must switch that